# Divide the set into group of two

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, set

Given is a set of elements. You have to divide them into groups of two, such that the difference between the sum of elements of an individual group is minimum.

example:

```
5
4 6 7 2 1
```

two groups are: `{4,6}` and `{7,2,1}`.

My approach: I have come across only the brute force solution of this problem, i.e. generate all the subsets `(2^n)` of the set using bit shifting technique.

I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [divide an array into two sets with minimal difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597180/divide-an-array-into-two-sets-with-minimal-difference)

Comment: @H2CO3 this will not work I can give you a counter example: `{1,2,2,2,7}`

Comment: H2CO3, please post your answers as answers, not comments.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Proof please, I don't see what's wrong with that particular case.

Comment: @H2CO3 you will put 1 and 7 in the same group as being the minimal and maximal elements, while the best solution is in fact `{1,2,2,2}` and `{7}` having difference of 1

Comment: @H2CO3 may we discuss this in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25583/divide-the-set-into-group-of-two)

Comment: This is a *knapsack problem*, which is NP and has a pseudo polynomial solution based on DP. This problem must be a duplicate of something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of giving you the solution I will give you two tips:

1. Calculate the sum of all elements and instead of solving the original problem. Denote this `S`. Solve a problem stated as follows - find a subset of the given numbers with sum no more than the `S/2`. The remaining numbers will form the other subset.
2. The problem I describe above is very simplified [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with equal costs of all elements. Again it can be solved using [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)(but in this case it will be way simpler than the one used for the classical knapsack problem)