# Partition a set into two subsets so that the difference of the sum is minimum and return the two subsets

Tags: algorithm, set, partitioning

There are many questions related to this, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223010/how-to-divide-a-set-of-numbers-into-two-sets-such-that-the-difference-of-their-s).

However, all of the answers focus on finding the minimum absolute sum. I'm trying to use some of the approaches laid out in the various answers, but I care less about returning the sum and more about returning the two subsets (or the first found best if there are multiple solutions).

Is there a way to do this without it being NP-hard?

My use-case is that I have a set of elements of various heights, and I need to arrange those elements into two columns (two arrays) to minimize the total maximum height of the elements when they are stacked next to each other. I have a solution that gives a decent result most of the time, but it isn't always accurate. I'm hoping to not have to calculate every single combination of two sets to get to an ideal solution.

*I'm aware there is optimization to be had below on removing items from the array and calculating the sum.

```js
// Input is always ordered by size
let inputWorking = [{
    item: 'a',
    size: 5
  },
  {
    item: 'b',
    size: 6
  },
  {
    item: 'c',
    size: 7
  },
  {
    item: 'd',
    size: 8
  },
];

let inputNotWorking = [{
    item: 'a',
    size: 14
  },
  {
    item: 'b',
    size: 14
  },
  {
    item: 'c',
    size: 20
  },
  {
    item: 'd',
    size: 20
  },
  {
    item: 'e',
    size: 21
  },
];


console.log('Output is correct', pushSides(inputWorking));

// Best fit would be [a,b,c], [d,e] with a max height of 48
console.log('Output is incorrect', pushSides(inputNotWorking));


function pushSides(items, ls = [], rs = []) {
  if (items.length === 0) {
    const leftSize = this.sumSizes(ls);
    const rightSize = this.sumSizes(rs);
    return {
      left: ls,
      right: rs,
      maxHeight: leftSize > rightSize ? leftSize : rightSize
    };
  }

  const lastItem = items[items.length - 1];
  const result = this.pushToIdealSide(lastItem, ls, rs);
  // Remove item we used
  items = items.filter(t => t !== lastItem);
  return pushSides(items, result.ls, result.rs);
}

function pushToIdealSide(nextItem, ls = [], rs = []) {
  if (this.sumSizes(rs) + nextItem.size > this.sumSizes(ls) + nextItem.size) {
    ls.push(nextItem);
  } else {
    rs.push(nextItem);
  }

  return {
    ls,
    rs
  };
}

function sumSizes(itemSizeArray) {
  return itemSizeArray.map(c => c.size)
    .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
}
```

Comment: One approach that comes to mind is to find the value of the 2 sums that have the least absolute difference and then going through the array and trying to take numbers such that they add up to the sum of one of those 2 values. The remaining elements are your second partition.

Comment: The hard part is ` trying to take numbers such that they add up to the sum of one of those 2 values` you end up with the same problem having to try a lot of combiantions.  For example if your sum for one side is 11 and you have 4,4,2,11... That would be a brute force approach, perhaps could have some optimizations, but i'd be just as well off creating every possible combination of arrays... No?

Comment: As I understand our partitions don't need to by contiguous subarrays. So we can sort and try to find one of the numbers using a 2 pointer approach? I'm not sure if we can do it greedily. The fact that we know for sure that a subset of the array adds up to one of those nums may help here.

Comment: You can use dynamic programming to solve the subset sum problem, provided that the sum of all the heights is a reasonably small integer.

Comment: Does this help - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partition-a-set-into-two-subsets-such-that-the-difference-of-subset-sums-is-minimum/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function version of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), so it is FNP-complete (and thus at least as hard as NP-complete). You can also phrase the question as a function version of Subset-Sum. Luckily, it has a pseudopolynomial solution and often solvable quickly in practice.

It's more useful to consider an equivalent form of your problem: Given a multiset of integers `S`, whose sum is `T`, find a subset of `S` whose sum is at most `T/2` and as close to `T/2` as possible. This subset is just the subset with smaller sum from your problem, so the other subset is the rest of `S`.

Given an algorithm (such as the one you link in the other post) that merely finds the optimal-sum-at-most-half (or, equivalently, the minimum absolute difference), there is usually a straightforward way to modify it to get the actual subset. When generating a list of subset-sums, also store the index of an element that generated that subset-sum. Then, at the end, we can backtrack from our final found sum to recover the elements.

For a simple example, if our array is [1, 5, 8], we might generate all subset sums by adding elements one at a time:

```c
Sums-Dict: Hashmap from subset-sums to last added element for that sum.
Initial Sums: {0: null}

Add element 1:
Sums-Dict = {0: null, 1: 1}

Add element 5:
Sums-Dict = {0: null, 1: 1, 5: 5, 6: 5}

Add element 8:
Sums-Dict = {0: null, 1: 1, 5: 5, 6: 5, 8: 8, 9: 8, 13: 8, 14: 8}
```

Then to backtrack, we use a process similar to backtracking in the knapsack-problem to output a solution:

```c
Find a closest sum to (1+5+8)/2, for example '6'.

Backtracking:
Used-elements = [], Current Sum = 6.
Sums-Dict[6] = 5: add 5 to used-elements, subtract 5 from current sum

Used-elements = [5], Current Sum = 1.
Sums-Dict[1] = 1: add 1 to used-elements, subtract 1 from current sum


Used-elements = [5, 1], Current Sum = 0.
Sums-Dict[0] = null: stop. We have found the subset that summed to '6'.
```

The classic dynamic-programming solution can be trivially modified to store that extra information for each sum; if the numbers are small, this is your best bet. I've included a Python implementation for subset-sum with a core algorithm and notation based on [the Schroeppel-Shamir](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0210033) paper. This is a meet-in-the-middle version of the naive inclusion/exclusion solution to subset-sum. It's more complex than the brute-force approach, but runs in `O(2^(n/2) * n/4)` time and takes `O(2^(n/4))` space, so is a practical solution for larger inputs.

```py
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple
import collections
import math
import heapq


class SubsetSumSolver:
    """Solves the subset-sum and partition optimization problems.
    Useful when values or goal sum are too large for dynamic programming"""

    def __init__(self, nums: List[int]):

        # Strip all zeros. Not necessary, but a useful optimization for speed
        self.orig_zeros = nums.count(0)
        self.nums = sorted(x for x in nums if x != 0)

        self.n = len(self.nums)

    def all_subset_sums(self, left_bound: int, right_bound: int) -> Dict[int, int]:
        """Return a subset-sum dictionary, mapping subset-sums of
        nums[left_bound:right_bound] to any index of an element in that subset-sum."""

        all_sums = {0: self.n + 1}
        for i in range(left_bound, right_bound):
            # Want old sums to remain/take priority
            new_sums = {self.nums[i] + elem: i for elem in all_sums}
            new_sums.update(all_sums)
            all_sums = new_sums

        return all_sums

    def recover_sum_members(self, sum_dict: Dict[int, int], found_sum: int) -> List[int]:
        """Given a subset-sum dictionary and a sum, return a set of elements
        from nums that formed that sum."""

        answer = []
        curr_sum = found_sum
        while curr_sum != 0:
            next_elem_index = sum_dict[curr_sum]
            next_elem = self.nums[next_elem_index]
            answer.append(next_elem)
            curr_sum -= next_elem

            assert len(answer) <= self.n

        return answer

    def min_absolute_difference(self, goal: float) -> List[int]:
        """Implement Schroeppel and Shamir alg. for subset sum
        Runs in O(2^(n/2) * n/4) time, takes O(2^(n/4)) space
        Returns a subset of self.nums whose sum is as close to goal as possible.
        """

        if self.n < 8:
            # Direct solution when n < 8; not worth splitting into 4 groups.
            all_sums_dict = self.all_subset_sums(0, self.n)
            best_diff_seen, best_sum = min(((abs(x - goal), x) for x in all_sums_dict),
                                           key=lambda pair: pair[0])
            return self.recover_sum_members(all_sums_dict, best_sum)

        # Split nums into 4 equal-length parts (or as close as possible)
        half = self.n // 2
        bounds = [0, half // 2, half, half + (self.n - half) // 2, self.n]
        # first_arr = nums[bounds[0]:bounds[1]]
        # sec_arr = nums[bounds[1]:bounds[2]]
        # third_arr = nums[bounds[2]:bounds[3]]
        # fourth_arr = nums[bounds[3]:bounds[4]]

        first_table_dict = self.all_subset_sums(bounds[0], bounds[1])
        first_table = list(first_table_dict.keys())

        sec_table_dict = self.all_subset_sums(bounds[1], bounds[2])
        sec_table = sorted(sec_table_dict.keys())

        third_table_dict = self.all_subset_sums(bounds[2], bounds[3])
        third_table = list(third_table_dict.keys())

        fourth_table_dict = self.all_subset_sums(bounds[3], bounds[4])
        fourth_table = sorted(fourth_table_dict.keys(), reverse=True)

        # min_heap stores pairs of problems from T1 and T2, and
        # makes the pair with smallest sum in front of the heap
        # Format: (sum, T1-index, T2-index) triplets
        min_heap = [(x + sec_table[0], i, 0) for i, x in enumerate(first_table)]

        # max_heap stores pairs of problems from T3 and T4, and
        # makes the pair with largest sum in front of the heap
        # Format: (-sum, T3-index, T4-index) triplets
        max_heap = [(-(x + fourth_table[0]), i, 0) for i, x in enumerate(third_table)]

        heapq.heapify(min_heap)
        heapq.heapify(max_heap)

        best_diff_seen = math.inf
        best_diff_indices = []

        while len(min_heap) != 0 and len(max_heap) != 0:
            smallest, p1, p2 = min_heap[0]
            largest, p3, p4 = max_heap[0]
            largest = -largest

            ans_here = smallest + largest
            if abs(goal - ans_here) < best_diff_seen:
                best_diff_seen = abs(goal - ans_here)
                best_diff_indices = (p1, p2, p3, p4)

            if ans_here <= goal:  # Want sum to increase, so increase p2
                heapq.heappop(min_heap)
                if p2 + 1 != len(sec_table):
                    heapq.heappush(min_heap,
                                   (first_table[p1] + sec_table[p2 + 1], p1, p2 + 1))
            else:  # Want sum to decrease. so increase p4
                heapq.heappop(max_heap)
                if p4 + 1 != len(fourth_table):
                    heapq.heappush(max_heap,
                                   (-(third_table[p3] + fourth_table[p4 + 1]), p3, p4 + 1))

        sum_ans = []
        p1, p2, p3, p4 = best_diff_indices

        sum_ans.extend(self.recover_sum_members(first_table_dict, first_table[p1]))
        sum_ans.extend(self.recover_sum_members(sec_table_dict, sec_table[p2]))
        sum_ans.extend(self.recover_sum_members(third_table_dict, third_table[p3]))
        sum_ans.extend(self.recover_sum_members(fourth_table_dict, fourth_table[p4]))

        return sum_ans

    def solve_partition(self) -> Tuple[List[int], List[int]]:
        """Return a partition of nums into (smaller_sum_set, larger_sum_set)
        Finds a partition whose sum-difference is minimum.
        """
        total_sum = sum(self.nums)
        frequency_counts = collections.Counter(self.nums)
        first_subset = self.min_absolute_difference(goal=total_sum / 2.0)
        if self.orig_zeros != 0:
            first_subset.extend([0] * self.orig_zeros)

        remaining_subset = frequency_counts - collections.Counter(first_subset)
        remaining_subset = list(remaining_subset.elements())
        if sum(first_subset) <= sum(remaining_subset):
            return (first_subset, remaining_subset)
        else:
            return (remaining_subset, first_subset)
```

You can call it like so, on any array of integers (practical up to n=100 elements):

```py
Solver = SubsetSumSolver([1, 5, 5, 6, 7, 10, 20])
print(Solver.solve_partition())

>>> ([10, 6, 5, 5, 1], [7, 20])
```